# how can I convert Bitmap to String, String to bitmap in kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I am trying to write the code I used to use in Java, but it does not seem to work in kotlin.

// in java

```
 public String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap){
     ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);
     byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
     String temp=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
     return temp;}

  // iam try like this
  // Base.encodeToString not work
  // that work is like this But request for Requires API O
  fun BitMapToString(bitmap: Bitmap): String {
     val base = ByteArrayOutputStream()
     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, base)
     val b = base.toByteArray()
     return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(b)
  }
```

how can I convert from bitmap to String in kotlin?

Comment: If your code "did not work" you need to fix your code. By this I want to make obvious to you that your question is not clear enough. What unwanted behaviour does occur? What wanted behaviour does not occcur? What warnings or error messages do you get (quote completeley and verbatim)? What is the code that is not working(we do of course not konw, show it)?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain that, giving details on "confert"/"convert". How did you try to convert? By using identical code? Or did you change anything?

Answer (score 2):

Just write this code:

```
fun BitMapToString(bitmap: Bitmap): String {
    val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos)
    val b = baos.toByteArray()
    return Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT)
}
```

Comment: the code will not work and will not be read by IDE .. please check the code first if you want to answer

Comment: @abdul It's working fine here and there is no error on my end. Are you using Android Studio for that? Because I am using an Android class Base64.

Comment: oh yeah sorry ,, i wear android studio ,, then how i to implement its Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

That is all. You just have to decode the base 64 string first into a byte array.:

```
val imageBytes = Base64.decode(string, 0)
val image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.size)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code that showed as wrong and it worked that way

```
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    fun BitMapToString(bitmap: Bitmap): String {
        val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos)
        val b = baos.toByteArray()
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(b)
    }
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code and explain how it answers the question. Code only answers are bad and might get downvoted. Thanks!